# ¿Por qué no puedo importar un respaldo de MySQL en un ordenador nuevo?

Tags: mysql, php7

Tengo una web, aplicación online, que funciona perfectamente en un ordenador donde la he creado.
Para su uso, el cliente sube un respaldo cada vez que lo utiliza y lo descarga al dejar de utilizarla. La importación la hace perfecta y la he probado online en varios ordenadores y funciona perfectamente, pero hay un ordenador en el que he instalado todo igual que en el anterior y no me funciona el respaldo. Os adjunto el comando que utilizo.

¿Por qué puede pasar que sólo en este ordenador (con el mismo sistema operativo que los anteriores) sucede esto? Con un archivo *.sql lo importo sin problemas con phpmyadmin, pero a través de el siguiente comando no me funciona:

```
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' --password="'.$mysqlPassword .'" ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output,$worked);
echo('Valor de  exec()...' . $worked);
switch($worked)
{
case 0:
echo 'Los datos del archivo ' .$mysqlImportFilename .' se han importado correctamente a la base de datos ' .$mysqlDatabaseName ;
break;
case 1:
echo 'Se ha producido un error durante la importación. Por favor, compruebe si el archivo está en la misma carpeta que este script. Compruebe también los siguientes datos de nuevo: <br/><br/><table><tr><td>Nombre de la base de datos MySQL:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>Nombre de usuario MySQL:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>Contraseña MySQL:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>Nombre de host MySQL:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>Nombre de archivo de la importación de MySQL:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
```

El valor que arroja de `exec()` es -1073741515 cuando debiera dar 0 ó 1.

Comment: Deberías revisar el valor de `$output` o abrir directamente la sesión de MySQL y ver los mensajes que arroja, o en su defecto hacer: `SHOW WARNINGS`.

Comment: ¿Está mysql instalado en ese equipo? ¿Es la misma versión que en los otros? ¿Son correctas las credenciales? ¿De qué tipo es el archivo `$mysqlImportFilename`?